# How to limit the contents of a collection in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

Suppose I have an entity

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Item> items;

    // probably getters and setters returning the collection

}
```

Now I wish to create some kind of a filter mechanism that would remove particular items.

For instance, I'd want a filter/predicate/supervisor/... that would:

- limit the list to, say, 10 newest (comparing `item.getDate()`)
- limit the list to only items newer than a date (again, `item.getDate()` to compare)
- limit the list to items whose names start with `"A"` (`item.getName()` and some logic)
- or do any other pluggable logic...

I'd want this "filter" to be executed after loading from DB (so that clients won't ever see the not-matching items e.g. too old to show), and also when the entity is stored/updated to the DB (so no invalid items are saved).

Is it possible? In JPA2 I'd play around with the `@PrePersist`, `@PostLoad` (etc.) hooks and do the filtering in the callbacks, but in Hibernate (using the `Session` interface and not `EntityManager`) I have no clue what to do.

Comment: That should be your business logic. It should be out of the entity.

Comment: @JBNizet but where should I place it so that I can guarantee the `Person` is in a valid state? In the repository/DAO? process it every time its loaded/saved?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things that may be of use:

**Hibernate Filters (non-JPA compliant):**

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html

**Hibernate @Where annotation (non-JPA compliant):**

http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/example-where-hibernate

**Database View (JPA compliant)**

Create a database view of the filtered data and Map an Entity to that.